# bash completion _parse_help broken?

Tags: bash, bash-completion, command-line-arguments

In order to get easy bash completion for my scripts' command line switches, I have been exploring the _parse_help function in /etc/bash_completion (debian sid, bash v4.2-1, bash-completion v1:1.99-3).

My script generates a help message in what I believe to be standard GNU format:

```
MYSCRIPT [OPTIONS]

Usage:
  -h, --help     Show this help message
  -o, --option   Some option
```

I then activate completion via `complete -F _parse_help ./myscript`.

Unfortunately this does not give the desired result. Upon first tab `./myscript <TAB>` (note, just a single keypress) an unformatted list appears containing --help and --option, not the shortened versions. Worse, completion of either option fails. In fact, just typing a dash causes _parse_help to completely stop generating output.

The whole thing feels very much broken, and I cannot find much reference of it online. Is this function perhaps considered obsolete? Is there another standard method of command line completion based on parsing --help output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [bash reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html#Programmable-Completion-Builtins) the `-F function` expects to read the word list from a variable `COMPREPLY`

It would appear that `_parse_help` does not set this required variable and would therefor not be suited as a function for `complete -F`. The output is obviously echo'd as is evident from executing the function.

```
$ _parse_help ./myscript 
-h
--help
-o
--option
```

@gertjan What you were attempting can be accomplished using the `-W wordlist` option instead.

```
$ complete -W "$(_parse_help ./myscript)" ./myscript 
$ ./myscript -
--help    --option  -h        -o
$ ./myscript --
--help    --option
$ ./myscript --help
```

Completion works as expected and `--h` will complete `--help` or where there were multiple arguments like with "--" it will only list the appropriate options.

If we were trying to use a function however it is not sufficient alone to only set `COMPREPLY` as you will see from the next example.

**NOTE:** `COMPREPLY` is a bash array and requires the brackets `()` when set

```
$ function _myscript () { 
>     COMPREPLY=($(_parse_help ./myscript))
> }
$ complete -F _myscript ./myscript 
$ ./myscript -
--help    --option  -h        -o
$ ./myscript --
--help    --option  -h        -o
$ ./myscript --help
--help    --option  -h        -o
```

As you can see, even though the options are displayed, `complete` now expects us to do the filtering. We can accomplish this with `compgen` but first we need to determine what the current argument is to filter against. The function `_get_comp_words_by_ref` can help with this by populating the `$cur` variable, as per our final example.

The complete implementation using a function with `_parse_help` for bash completion.

```
$ function _myscript () {
>     _get_comp_words_by_ref cur
>     COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "$(_parse_help ./myscript)" -- "$cur"))
> }
$ complete -F _myscript ./myscript 
$ ./myscript - 
--help    --option  -h        -o
$ ./myscript --
--help    --option
$ ./myscript --help
```

nJoy!

Comment: Ah yes, that works. Perfect. Thanks a lot, I really couldn't figure that one out!